# Datastore. Object attribute not found although it exists in the Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

An ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False) attribute is not found when the code performs a check on whether the user can perform an action.

I've tried using an ndb.StringProperty instead of the Boolean Property, but it makes no difference. Other attributes within the Property are recognised. 
Most interestingly, if I place a {{user.org_setup_done}} tag in jinja2 within the HTML, it returns correctly the value of the attribute, i.e. False.

In other words, I know the attribute is correctly created and stored within the User entity as I can see it in the datastore and call it with a jinja2 tag in the HTML. However when I perform a check on it it is not found.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    """
    model for storing user information
    """
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)  # the users email, as username
    pass_hash = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)  # the users hashed password
    org_setup_done = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)  # if the user has completed the org profile for creating events


class OrgCreateCompStartHandler(BaseHandler):
    """handler that lets you start creating an event by choosing series, date, name, start time and venue"""

    def get(self):
        try:
            user = self.user_obj()  # get the user object from session, returns None if no session exists

            if user.org_setup_done:  # check to see if the user is org_ready. If yes, continue with the event creation,
                # if no then redirect to the profile page for event organisers.
                # : TEMPLATE VALUES
                template_values = {
                    'user': user,
                }
                # : RENDER TEMPLATE
                self.render_template(ROUTE, 'org-create.html', template_values)

            else:
                self.redirect("/")

        except Exception, e:
            logging.error("ERROR is %s" % e)
            logging.exception("EXC is %s" % e)
            self.redirect("/oops")  # unexpected error
```

Expected Result should be for the org-create.html page to render after the code checks that the org_setup_done attribute is True.

Actual Result is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\events.py", line 2433, in get
    if user.org_setup_done:  
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'org_setup_done'
```

Does anyone have any idea on this? I'm truly confused by this one.

Comment: Did you by any chance create any User objects *before* adding the `org_setup_done` property or adding its default value into the model?

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks. I've deleted the Users created previously and flushed memchache to make sure that isn't the problem. I changed the name of the attribute to something completely arbitrary, and made it a String instead of Boolean and removed the default value, hardcoding "False" instead. I still have the same error message. Other attributes, i.e. email, are found and if the org-create.html template is rendered then {{ user.email }} returns the value correctly while {{ user.arbitrary value }} is not found. I've been looking at this for close to 2 days now and have no idea how to fix this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user = self.user_obj()  # get the user object from session, returns None if no session exists
```

I think your `User` model is clashing with the built-in `User` model from `webapp2`

You could config webapp2 to use your `User` model

```
webapp_app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
config={
    ...
    'webapp2_extras.auth': {'user_model': 'path.to.my.user_model_file.User'},
})
```

However `webapp2`'s session code probably has some assumptions about what fields / functions the `User` object has, so you'd need to implement those in your `User`. 
You could also just have your User model inherit the webapp2 one

```
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User as _webapp2_User

class User(_webapp2_User):
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, although I'm not sure. I've used a model called User in a previous simple project and had no similar issues. I will try to change the model name (although will cause issues with the live version) and see if it works. Cheers.

Comment: There was a conflict, I changed the User model name to Users and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Alex it seems there was conflict between webapp2's built in User model and the User model I created.

Although I am also not sure if the issue is actually between the session code from webapp2 and my own session code created when I log in as admin.

i.e. as this site is not live yet, it is behind a google login as admin in the app.yaml file. As soon as I sign in on the dev server a session cookie is created by webapp2. Then, when I create a new user for the site, another session cookie is created, this time via my BaseHandler in dispatch. My knowledge of the code is not sufficient to know if the conflict actually lies in those 2 session cookies, but perhaps it is.